# jquery nested selection does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating a select button in HTML and jQuery but button`s selection in jQuery does not work.
my HTML file is:

```
<div class="back_gray_light sideBar_content" id="sideBar_mostRate_selectYear">
        <div id="sideBar_selectYear">
            <div id="sideBar_selectYear_button">
                <button type="button">
                    <img src="/static/icons/100film/arrow_button.png">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="sideBar_selectedYear">
                <p>
                    1394
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="sideBar_allYears_hide">
                <button type="button" class="sideBar_year_hide sideBar_year_item">
                    <p>
                        1394
                    </p>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="sideBar_year_hide sideBar_year_item">
                    <p>
                        1393
                    </p>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my jQuery file is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('start');

    $('#sideBar_selectYear_button button').click(function(event){
        console.log('select year');
        $('#sideBar_allYears_hide').slideDown();
    });

});
```

the output in console is:

```
start
```

and my program does not print `select year`.

Comment: Could be your `CSS` styling

Comment: Typo: you're using a class selector when the element has an `id`. Change `$('.sideBar_allYears_hide')` to `$('#sideBar_allYears_hide')` Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/mafcqk35/ You can also see from the fiddle that the `select year` is also shown. There's no reason that that would not work, assuming there are no other errors in your code.

Comment: of course as per your program `select year` will be printed only when you click on the button. there is no problem with html and function. Do you want the  `select year` to be printed on page load?

Comment: There is a possibility you have two of the same ID on the page in that case it will only work on the first one it finds

Comment: It works fine here! See your code: https://jsfiddle.net/d3bqmhq1/ . Maybe as John suggest that you have a problem in the rest of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below demo. I updated your code. I just replaced console.log with Alert so you can see result on browser. Your code is working perfectly just issue with # and . . If you use class then you have to use dot(.) before class name and if you use id then you have to hase(#) before id name.

i just hide sideBar_allYears_hide div to show slidedown functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('start');
    $('#sideBar_selectYear_button button').click(function(event){
        alert('select year');
        $('#sideBar_allYears_hide').slideDown();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back_gray_light sideBar_content" id="sideBar_mostRate_selectYear">
        <div id="sideBar_selectYear">
            <div id="sideBar_selectYear_button">
                <button type="button">
                    <img src="/static/icons/100film/arrow_button.png">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="sideBar_selectedYear">
                <p>
                    1394
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="sideBar_allYears_hide" style="Display:none;">
                <button type="button" class="sideBar_year_hide sideBar_year_item">
                    <p>
                        1394
                    </p>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="sideBar_year_hide sideBar_year_item">
                    <p>
                        1393
                    </p>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just need to change this line.

```
$('.sideBar_allYears_hide').slideDown();
```

to this

```
$('#sideBar_allYears_hide').slideDown();
```

simple id `#` class `.` swap mistake

EDIT:

To solve the main problem you need to do this jquery selector instead before your click:

```
$('#sideBar_selectYear_button [type=button]')
```

Edit:
But now that I look back at it there seems to be nothing wrong with the original. Since the element is a button element. So I don't really see that as an issue.

```
$('#sideBar_selectYear_button button')
```

Comment: But it should print 'select year' regardless

Comment: Still a problem though

Answer (score 1):

Like already said you need to change the "." with "#", hover your are just binding the function to the click event, you may want also to trigger it by code or actually clicking on that "#sideBar_selectYear_button button" to log "select year" to the console